# Extract file from Ressources

Tags: c#, wpf, stream, zip

I am attempting to extract a .zip file from a ressource in my project, and so found this great sample online, that uses SharpZipLib:

```
try
{
   ResourceManager objResMgr = new ResourceManager("My_Project.MyFile", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
   byte[] objData = (byte[])objResMgr.GetObject("MyFile.zip");
   MemoryStream objMS = new MemoryStream(objData);
   ZipInputStream objZIP = new ZipInputStream(objMS);
   ZipEntry theEntry;
   while ((theEntry = objZIP.GetNextEntry()) != null)
   {
       FileStream streamWriter =
       File.Create(System.IO.Path.Combine("C:/", theEntry.Name));
       int size = objData.Length;
       byte[] data = new byte[size];
       while (true)
       {
           size = objZIP.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
           if (size > 0)
           {
              streamWriter.Write(data, 0, size);
           }
           else
           {
              break;
           }
      }
      streamWriter.Close();
   }
   objZIP.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

The problem is, that when I run my code, I receive an exception asking me to check that "My_Project.MyFile.ressources" has correctly been embedded or linked in the assembly "My Project".
This shows up if the Build Action of my zip is "Ressource" or "Embedded Ressource". I'm sure that the zip file does end up in the .exe, because of it's size.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is the string that you use for the first parameter of the `ResourceManager` constructor.

You use "My_Project.MyFile". For this to work you would have to have a .resx resources file called "MyFile.resx" within your My_Project project (it is not the name of the file you have embedded as a resource). The resx file is like a catalogue of resources that the resource manager uses.

To make use of the code you have, add a new resources file (.resx) to the project, open it in VS, add the file as a new resource and then it will be available using the `ResourceManager`.